# How to close an alert automtically using js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a tool to book the class from our school website using js.

But I meet this problem:

When the number of student meets the maxinum number, the website will appear an alert which stop my code running.

I have tried this method to close it:

```
window.alert=function(){return true};
```

But it doesn't work.

And the following is the function which can be active after I pretend to click the add-list-button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK0hz.png)

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get rid of an alert?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, I want to close it automatically and let my tool continue to work.

Comment: It is impossible to say how it all works without looking into the website. You need to investigate the code, understand how and where this alert is created ad inject this code **before** it is being called from the website's code. In general, your approach is the right way to do this, even though it is a bad idea.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I think the alert is created when there is wrong in submitting form(In my example, student can not book the class which is full). So do you mean that there is no way to close this alert automatically after it is created? If so, I should try another way to code.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is AWFUL practice. But if you're hamstrung by existing code, sometimes you have to make do.

```
//the following code suppresses the first alert on the website
var originalAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {
    window.alert = originalAlert;
};
```

Comment: It seems the same with the code I have tried which is written in the problem description.
And it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should run this piece of code before the external code runs, so before document ready.